# Most performant way to concatenate the contents of a generator plus another vector

Tags: arrays, performance, julia

I want to produce an array, and I know I want it to end with a fixed set of values, say `3,2,1`.

Let's say I want to produce the same result as this:

```
julia> N = 10;

julia> [(i^2 for i in 1:N)..., 3, 2, 1]
13-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   4
   9
  16
  25
  36
  49
  64
  81
 100
   3
   2
   1
```

for very long Ns (and potentially for long suffixes as well).

I know that in general, constructing an array via vcat is preferable to constructing it via splatting. For example:

```
julia> let a = fill(0.0, 1000)
           @btime [$a..., $10.0]
       end;
  34.250 μs (1002 allocations: 23.64 KiB)

julia> let a = fill(0.0, 1000)
           @btime [$a; $10.0]
       end;
  685.833 ns (18 allocations: 8.36 KiB)
```

Is there a penalty for splatting the generator here? Is there a better alternative?

Here is the baseline to compare against:

```
julia> @btime [(i^2 for i in 1:$1000)..., 3, 2, 1];
  52.541 μs (2477 allocations: 93.95 KiB)
```

Of course I tried vcatting, but the generator isn't an array, so it doesn't collect its contents, it simply collects the array:

```
julia> [(i^2 for i in 1:10); 3; 2; 1]
4-element Vector{Any}:
  Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64}, var"#47#48"}(var"#47#48"(), 1:10)
 3
 2
 1
```

Comment: For sure there's a penalty. The alternative is to `collect` the generator first, e.g. `vcat([i^2 for i in 1:1000], 3, 2, 1)` is 50x faster. You can go a little faster by allocating once, e.g. `copyto!(zeros(10), (i^2 for i in 1:7))`.

Answer (score 2):

Manually writing out the array-builder operation with for-loops is faster, which isn't too surprising I suppose.

```
julia> function make_array_321(N)
           a = sizehint!(Int[], N + 3)
           for i in 1:N
               push!(a, i^2)
           end
           append!(a, (3,2,1))
           return a
       end
make_array_321 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime make_array_321($1000);
  3.234 μs (2 allocations: 8.00 KiB)

julia>
```

Is there a declarative array-builder syntax that looks more like what I originally wrote, but performs like this loop code?

The loop is clearly easier to read, and that leads people to write it in this style. I would love to have a similarly readable yet performant alternative to present. Thank you!

Comment: :o Somehow this is even faster, even with the extra copy, which i don't understand. Is it because it can do better SIMD than the version I wrote?:
```julia> @btime [collect((i^2 for i in 1:$1000)); 3; 2; 1];
  771.283 ns (14 allocations: 16.20 KiB)```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest alternative I've tested uses proper pre-allocation instead of `sizehint!` and `push!`:

```
function myarr(N)
    a = Vector{Int}(undef, N + 3)
    for i in 1:N
        a[i] = i^2
    end
    a[N+1] = 3
    a[N+2] = 2
    a[N+3] = 1
    return a
end
```

Comment: And you can probably do even better with inbounds. I wonder why this is faster than push.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the generator and the individual elements in a vector constructor within `[ ]` is faster, since it does vcat() under the hood which is fast, because Base.cat can be fast:

```
julia> @code_lowered [collect((i^2 for i in 1:1000)); 3; 2; 1]
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (:dims,)
│   %2 = Core.apply_type(Core.NamedTuple, %1)
│   %3 = Base.Val(1)
│   %4 = Core.tuple(%3)
│   %5 = (%2)(%4)
│   %6 = Core.tuple(%5, Base.cat)
│   %7 = Core._apply_iterate(Base.iterate, Core.kwcall, %6, A)
└──      return %7
)

julia> @code_lowered vcat(collect((i^2 for i in 1:1000)), 3, 2, 1)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (:dims,)
│   %2 = Core.apply_type(Core.NamedTuple, %1)
│   %3 = Base.Val(1)
│   %4 = Core.tuple(%3)
│   %5 = (%2)(%4)
│   %6 = Core.tuple(%5, Base.cat)
│   %7 = Core._apply_iterate(Base.iterate, Core.kwcall, %6, A)
└──      return %7
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to materialize (and in many scenarios you don't) and both vectors are large enough the fastest will be a `mortar` that is available when `using BlockArrays`:

```
julia> x = collect(1:10_000);

julia> sfx = collect(1:100);

julia> @btime mortar([$x,$sfx]);
  81.677 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)
```

This is something like 1000 X faster than allocating code  for this size of array (given at the answer by @GKi) as simply allocations takes lots of time.

Comment: Shouldn't be the time creating the vectors also be included? At least in all cases I have shown it is included.

Comment: Good point. That is why I start my answer with "If you do not need to materialize". So sometimes you have one big vector and want to construct a new one with joining a suffix. The time to construct all elements of the vector will vary on the size and type of elements. The shortest time could be `Vector{Int}(undef,10_000)` which takes 500ns on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using
`[[i^2 for i in 1:N]; 3; 2; 1]` or
`[[i^2 for i in 1:N]; [3, 2, 1]]` or
`vcat([i^2 for i in 1:N], [3, 2, 1])` will be a way.

```
using BenchmarkTools

N = 100000

@btime [(i^2 for i in 1:$N)..., 3, 2, 1]       # @NHDaly
#  4.558 ms (299489 allocations: 9.78 MiB)

@btime begin                                   # @NHDaly
  a = sizehint!(Int[], $N + 3)
  for i in 1:$N
    push!(a, i^2)
  end
  append!(a, (3,2,1))
end
#  387.648 μs (2 allocations: 781.44 KiB)

@btime [collect((i^2 for i in 1:$N)); 3; 2; 1] # @NHDaly and @Bill
#  169.008 μs (16 allocations: 1.53 MiB)

@btime vcat([i^2 for i in 1:$N], [3, 2, 1])
#  165.751 μs (5 allocations: 1.53 MiB)

@btime vcat([i^2 for i in 1:$N], 3, 2, 1)      # @mcabbott
#  164.108 μs (16 allocations: 1.53 MiB)

@btime [[i^2 for i in 1:$N]; [3, 2, 1]]
#  161.984 μs (5 allocations: 1.53 MiB)

@btime [[i^2 for i in 1:$N]; 3; 2; 1]
#  158.117 μs (16 allocations: 1.53 MiB)

@btime begin                                   # @mcabbott modified
  x = copyto!(Vector{Int}(undef, $N+3), (i^2 for i in 1:$N))
  x[$N+1:end] = [3,2,1]
end
#  94.457 μs (3 allocations: 781.44 KiB)

@btime begin                                   # @mcabbott modified
  x = copyto!(Vector{Int}(undef, $N+3), (i^2 for i in 1:$N))
  x[$N+1] = 3; x[$N+2] = 2; x[$N+3] = 1        # @Dan Getz modified
end
#  92.363 μs (2 allocations: 781.36 KiB)

@btime [i > $N ? (3,2,1)[i - $N] : i^2 for i in 1:$N+3]  # @Dan Getz modified
#  83.296 μs (2 allocations: 781.36 KiB)

using BlockArrays
@btime begin                                   # @Przemyslaw Szufel modified
    x = [i^2 for i in 1:$N]
    y = [3, 2, 1]
    z = mortar([x,y])
end
#  76.453 μs (6 allocations: 781.59 KiB)

@btime begin                                   # @DNF
  x = Vector{Int}(undef, $N + 3)
  for i in 1:$N
    x[i] = i^2
  end
  x[$N+1] = 3; x[$N+2] = 2; x[$N+3] = 1
end
#  75.641 μs (2 allocations: 781.36 KiB)

@btime begin                                   # @DNF modified
  x = Vector{Int}(undef, $N + 3)
  for i in 1:$N
    @inbounds x[i] = i^2
  end
  x[$N+1] = 3; x[$N+2] = 2; x[$N+3] = 1
end
#  66.995 μs (2 allocations: 781.36 KiB)

#julia -t 4
@btime begin                                   # @DNF modified
  x = Vector{Int}(undef, $N + 3)
  Threads.@threads for i in 1:$N
    @inbounds x[i] = i^2
  end
  x[$N+1] = 3; x[$N+2] = 2; x[$N+3] = 1
end
#  60.184 μs (25 allocations: 783.61 KiB)
```

It should also be considered how the result is used afterwards. Especially in the case when the concatenation is not materialized.

```
using BenchmarkTools, BlockArrays

N = 100000
x = [i^2 for i in 1:N]
y = [3, 2, 1]

a = [x;y]
b = mortar([x,y])

@btime begin
    s = 0
    for i in $a
        s += i
    end
end
#  2.033 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

@btime begin
    s = 0
    for i in $b
        s += i
    end
end
#  225.174 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: The last one can be further sped by using `x[N] = 1; x[N+1] = 2; x[N+2] = 3` (but by a measly amount) and `x = [i > 1000 ? i - 1000 : i^2 for i in 1:1003]` speeds substantially.